# how to draw lines on a tensor?

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, tensor

I wanna draw lines on a tensor, just like how I do on a numpy.array one :

```
pts = [[160, 160], [280, 280]]
mask = np.zeros([640,640]).astype(np.uint8)
mask = cv2.line(mask, *pts, (255, 255), 15)
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
```

image show result:
[image]

The tensor like this:

```
mask_t = torch.zeros([640,640],dtype=torch.uint8).to(device)
```

How can I do for this?

Comment: opencv-python only support `numpy.ndarray`. So maybe you need convert the tensor twice: tensor->ndarray(apply `cv2.line()`)->tensor

Comment: @nnzzll maybe what I want is just a way on 'tensor'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using `einops` and `jaxtyping`:

```
from typing import Tuple

import torch
from einops import einsum, rearrange, reduce
from jaxtyping import Bool, Float
from torch import Tensor


def _generate_line_mask(
    shape: Tuple[int, int],
    start: Float[Tensor, "line 2"],
    end: Float[Tensor, "line 2"],
    width: float,
) -> Bool[Tensor, "height width"]:
    device = start.device

    # Generate a pixel grid.
    h, w = shape
    x = torch.arange(w, device=device) + 0.5
    y = torch.arange(h, device=device) + 0.5
    xy = torch.stack(torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="xy"), dim=-1)

    # Define a vector between the start and end points.
    delta = end - start
    delta_norm = delta.norm(dim=-1, keepdim=True)
    u_delta = delta / delta_norm

    # Define a vector between each pixel and the start point.
    indicator = xy - start[:, None, None]

    # Determine whether each pixel is inside the line in the parallel direction.
    parallel = einsum(u_delta, indicator, "l xy, l h w xy -> l h w")
    parallel_inside_line = (parallel <= delta_norm[..., None]) & (parallel > 0)

    # Determine whether each pixel is inside the line in the perpendicular direction.
    perpendicular = indicator - parallel[..., None] * u_delta[:, None, None]
    perpendicular_inside_line = perpendicular.norm(dim=-1) < (0.5 * width)

    return (parallel_inside_line & perpendicular_inside_line).any(dim=0)


def draw_lines(
    image: Float[Tensor, "3 height width"],
    start: Float[Tensor, "line 2"],
    end: Float[Tensor, "line 2"],
    color: Float[Tensor, "3"],
    width: float = 4.0,
    supersample: int = 5,
) -> Float[Tensor, "3 height width"]:
    _, h, w = image.shape
    s = supersample
    mask = _generate_line_mask((h * s, w * s), start * s, end * s, width * s)
    mask = reduce(mask.float(), "(h hs) (w ws) -> h w", "mean", hs=s, ws=s)

    # Paint the line on the image.
    return image * (1 - mask[None]) + color[:, None, None] * mask[None]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    image = torch.zeros((3, 256, 256), dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
    start = torch.tensor([[64, 64], [64, 192]], dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
    end = torch.tensor([[192, 192], [192, 64]], dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
    color = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1], dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
    image = draw_lines(image, start, end, color, width=4)

    from PIL import Image

    image = (image * 255).type(torch.uint8).cpu().numpy()
    image = rearrange(image, "c h w -> h w c")
    Image.fromarray(image).save("example.png")
```

The above code produces the following `example.png`:

[image: example of blue lines drawn on black background]